# conversion of epoch_time gives '1970-01-01' in mysql

Tags: mysql

I've column name `epoch_time` with a `varchar(255)` which is having approx 40,000 epoch time in it and I've tried to convert all of them into a equivalent date with this query `UPDATE table_name SET converted_into_date = FROM_UNIXTIME(epoch_time);`
but it is giving `1970-01-01 05:30:00` in all rows and the `datatype` of `converted_into_date` column is `varchar`. I've tried all the datatype but then it is returning `null` . working in maria_db.

Comment: Please show us some data, at least a few rows, from the `epoch_time` column.  Note that you should _not_ be storing numerical UNIX timestamp data as text.  This is the major problem which I see with what you are doing.

Comment: What is in your epoch_time column ? FROM_UNIXTIME() needs a very specific format, and you seem to have placed something else in your `epoch_time` column that FROM_UNIXTIME() cannot deal with. Show us some sample data.

Comment: `epoch_time                      datestamp`  
`1526019841742682        1970-01-01 05:30:00`  
**datestamp** is a converted time column.

Comment: @KshitizKatiyar Please try SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1526019841742682/1000000)

Comment: @PraveenE thanks..... it works

Comment: cool @KshitizKatiyar
Will post as answer. Might be helpful for others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try

> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1526019841742682/1000000)